Call to PHP nusoap service failing with error 500
I am new to writing and consuming WSDL web-services. I have written a  web-service in PHP for testing using nusoap library. Here is the code for login_api.php:
<?php
   require_once('path/to/nusoap.php');
   # Implement the "validateLogin" method
   function validateLogin($username, $password) {
       # Implement database logic here
      if ($username === 'admin' && $password === 'secret') {
         return "VALIDATED";
      } else {
         return "FAILED";
      }
   }
   
   # Create the server instance
   $server = new soap_server();
   $server->configureWSDL('login_api', 'urn:login_api');
   $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:login_api';
   
   # Register the "validateLogin" method
   $server->register('validateLogin', array('username' => 'xsd:string', 'password' => 'xsd:string'),
       array('return' => 'xsd:string'), 'urn:login_api#validateLogin', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'Validate user login');
   
   # Use the request to invoke the service
   $rawStream = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $input = json_decode($rawStream, true);
   $server->service($input);
?>

Here the jQuery code to consume the web-service:
<script type="text/javascript">
   data = { username: 'admin', password: 'secret' };
   $.post('https://cdn.kbcsurveyors.com/api/login_api.php', data, function(Result){
      // Parse the response as JSON
      console.log('JSON Response:', JSON.parse(Result));
      // Handle the XML response directly
      console.log('XML Response:', Result);
   }, 'xml').error(function(Result){
      console.log(Result.responseText);
   });
</script>

Call to the web-service fails on line console.log(Result.responseText); with following text in browser console:

POST https://cdn.kbcsurveyors.com/api/login_api.php 500 (Internal
Server Error) send @ jquery-1.9.0.js:8475 ajax @ jquery-1.9.0.js:7930
jQuery. @ jquery-1.9.0.js:7569 (anonymous) @ wsdl-test/:81
wsdl-test/:87 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
SOAP-ENV:BodySOAP-ENV:Fault</SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

URI to the web-service is

https://cdn.kbcsurveyors.com/api/login_api.php

I dont' understand what error am I making. Any help please?

SOAP is a very specific protocol, which is not normally used for communicating between browser and server - indeed , it's fairly unfashionable to use SOAP for anything. There's probably ways to do it if you really need to, but it's not what jQuery will do if you just ask for "XML", and certainly has nothing to do with JSON.
